# Passing RequestParam data to Spring RestController

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using `restTemplate.exchange`method to invoke one service from another service.My request url does accept a request parameter.

url is of the form`http://localhost:8035/sgapp/student/fetchDeptNo?sid`

In the conttroller it is written as

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/sgapp/student")
public class SiController{
     @GetMapping(value = "/fetchDeptNo",consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      public ResponseEntity<String> getSid(@RequestParam(name = "sid")String sid){
                  String sid = myRepo.getSidCode(sid);
                  System.out.println("sid received from DB::"+sid); 
                  return new ResponseEntity<String>(sid,HttpStatus.OK);
              }
        }
```

In the caller application I am invoking it as

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        Map paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        paramMap.put("sid", sidData);
        HttpEntity<String> sidRespnse = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8035/sgapp/student/fetchDeptNo", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class,
                paramMap);
```

But I'm getting folllowing exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular `exchange` method is used to substitute variables into the path.

If you want to pass query parameters, use `UriComponentsBuilder` to create the URL with query params:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = 
    UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl(rootUri)
        .queryParam("sid", sidData);
```

Then you can use RestTemplate as follows:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    builder.toUriString(),
    HttpMethod.GET,
    entity,
    String.class);
```